# docker install with tcp enabled 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker

Wondering if anyone knows how to install with tcp enabled? Something like below? I

```
yum install docker --tcp-enabled --host 0.0.0.0
```

I understand I can go and manual change OPTIONS in /etc/sysconfig/docker.

I am trying to provision a server with a fresh docker install through scripts and I do not want to log onto the box and make these changes, everytime a new version comes out. I also understand I can just use a script with sed/awk to do this, But just wondering if easier way, without having to maintain a script.

Comment: Is `/etc/docker/daemon.json` an option?

Comment: by default /etc/docker/daemon.json is not created, Do you know if I can just create daemon.json and that will take precedence over /etc/sysconfig/docker.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred solution is to use `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. This will let you add options to just about any install.

Note that I don't believe this will unset options that were defined on the command line, it's designed to let you use both. Those command line options are defined by your startup script, which from your description is systemd on a RedHat/CentOS environment with `/etc/sysconfig/docker` injected environment variables (you won't see this on other platforms like Debian). So if you need to remove an option, you'll still need to update your `/etc/sysconfig/docker`.